# How would I call a method from a class with a variable?

Tags: php, oop, variable-variables

Given this class:

```
class Tacobell{

    public function order_taco(){
        echo "3 Tacos, thank you.";
    }

    public function order_burrito(){
        echo "Cheesy bean and rice, please";
    }

}

$lunch = new Tacobell;
$lunch->order_burrito();
$lunch->order_taco();
```

How would I do something like this?

```
$myOrder = 'burrito';
$lunch->order_.$myOrder;
```

Obviously that code is bunk--but shows what I'm attempting to do better than trying to explain it away.

And maybe I'm going about this all wrong.  I thought about a method with a switch statement, pass in burrito or taco, then call the right method from there.  But then I have to know the end from the beginning, and I may potentially have lots of methods and I'd rather not have to update the switch statement everytime.

Thanks!

Comment: This could be done using objects, you can have classes for each item, each can conform to the same interface, then have a single order() method that will take a OrderItem object which could either be a BurritoOrderItem or a TacoOrderItem.  I always cringe when Reflection is needed or when you have variable method calls, it just isn't clean to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
class Tacobell {
    public function order_burrito() {
         echo "Bladibla.\n";
    }

    public function order($item) {
        if (method_exists($this, "order_$item")) {
            $this->{'order_' . $item}();
        } else {
            echo "Go away, we don't serve $item here.\n";
        }
    }
}
```

You would call it using $lunch->order('burrito');, which looks much cleaner to me. It puts all the uglyness in the method Tacobell::order.

Comment: All the answers so far have been what I needed, but this what I was looking for.  Thanks all.  I'm still not sure this is how I want to do it though, but for now it gets the most reuse out of my code.

Answer (score 3):

```
$lunch->{'order_' . $myOrder}();
```

I do agree the design is a little iffy, but that's how to do it at least.

Answer (score 2):

I think `call_user_func` is what you're looking for:

https://www.php.net/call_user_func

You can pass it the string you suggested.  See example #3 for calling a method of a class.

Answer (score 0):

simple enough

```
$order = 'order_burrito';
$lunch->$order();
```