# OOP in PHP: Class-function from a variable?

Tags: php, oop, class

Is it possible to call functions from class like this:

```
$class = new class;
$function_name = "do_the_thing";
$req = $class->$function_name();
```

Something similar solution, this doesn't seem to work?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936875/how-would-i-call-a-method-from-a-class-with-a-variable

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, that is know as **variable functions**, have a **[look at this.](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)**

**Example from PHP's official site:**

```
<?php
class Foo
{
    function Variable()
    {
        $name = 'Bar';
        $this->$name(); // This calls the Bar() method
    }

    function Bar()
    {
        echo "This is Bar";
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$funcname = "Variable";
$foo->$funcname();  // This calls $foo->Variable()

?>
```

In your case, make sure that the function `do_the_thing` exists. Also note that you are storing the return value of the function:

```
$req = $class->$function_name();
```

Try to see what the variable `$req` contains. For example this should give you info:

```
print_r($req); // or simple echo as per return value of your function
```

**Note:**

Variable functions won't work with language constructs such as `echo(), print(), unset(), isset(), empty(), include(), require()` and the like. Utilize wrapper functions to make use of any of these constructs as variable functions.

Comment: @MAS1: Yeah it is very important :)

Comment: It's also good because calling class functions this way is case insensitive! :)

Answer (score 8):

**My easiest example is:**

```
$class = new class;
$function_name = "do_the_thing";
$req = $class->${$function_name}();
```

**${$function_name}** is the trick

Also works with static methods:

```
$req = $class::{$function_name}();
```

Comment: I get an error using 
$req = $class->${$function_name}(); 
However the following seems to be the correct syntax
$req = $class->{$function_name}();

Comment: thanks @Martin for the fix. I will need to check again with the code where it comes from to see why I had this error.

Comment: Methods using variable variables, nice!

Answer (score 0):

Also try this (note the curly brackets {} ):

```
$class = new class;
$function_name = "do_the_thing";
$req = $class->{$function_name}();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`ReflectionClass`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php).

**Example:**

```
$functionName = 'myMethod';
$myClass = new MyClass();
$reflectionMyMethod = (new ReflectionClass($myClass))->getMethod($functionName);

$relectionMyMethod->invoke($myClass); // same as $myClass->myMethod();
```

Remember to catch ReflectionException If Method Not Exist.