# PHP calling class function dynamically by variables caughts exception

Tags: php, function, variables, dynamically-generated

I'am trying to call a public funtion of a class with variables(php7). Therfore I do:

```
$module = 'frontend\\modules\\rest\\models\\Member';
$action = 'view_profile'

$response = new $module();
$response = $response1->$action;
```

By calling $response1->$action I get the following error:

```
Undefined property: frontend\modules\rest\models\Member::$view_profile
```

I see that the systems try to call ...Member\$view_profile and this will not work. But why is the '$' before view_profile. I've tried several variantes, but the error with the $view_profile is always there. What is wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this other reply: [OOP in PHP: Class-function from a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657454/oop-in-php-class-function-from-a-variable) (cannot comment, sorry...)

Anyway, this is what you are after: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

```
<?php
class Foo
{
    function Variable()
    {
        $name = 'Bar';
        $this->$name(); // This calls the Bar() method
    }

    function Bar()
    {
        echo "This is Bar";
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$funcname = "Variable";
$foo->$funcname();  // This calls $foo->Variable()

?>
```

So I guess the only thing missing is the "()" after

```
$response1->$action;
```

Comment: Great Silvio! This was the missing thing, I haven't seen after 10 hours in front of the monitor! thx

Comment: Silvio, is it also possible to set a public class variable also this way? I mean with a generic variable like $foo->$var? How can I set a class variable with $var this way?

Comment: Yes of course, it works exactly the same:
$varname = "foo";
$this->$varname = "bar";
// now $this->foo == "bar";